# Dynamic counter for corollaries

Tags: counters, amsthm, chngcntr

I use the package `chngcntr` to number the Corollaries of a Theorem so they zero for the next Theorem, with the setting

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{cor}{theo}
```

and that works very nice, producing things like:

```
Theorem 1
  Corollary 1
  Corollary 2
Theorem 2
  Corollary 1
Theorem 3
  Corollary 1
  Corollary 2
```

but I would like to be able to take the number OUT of that isolated Corollary 1 of Theorem 2 and label it just plain "Corollary".

Any ideas how this could be done automatically?

The code that does show the result above is incredibly boring, but since it gets requested by SX first-responders here it is:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\theteo}{\arabic{teo}}

\newtheorem{col}{Corolário}
\renewcommand{\thecol}{\arabic{col}}


\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}

\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithin*{col}{teo}

\begin{document}

\begin{teo}
The first theorem
\end{teo}

   \begin{col}
     The first corollary
   \end{col}
   \begin{col}
     The second corollary
   \end{col}

\begin{teo}
The second theorem
\end{teo}

   \begin{col}
     Unique corollary to the theorem -- should have no number.
   \end{col}

\begin{teo}
The third theorem
\end{teo}

   \begin{col}
     The first corollary
   \end{col}
   \begin{col}
     The second corollary
   \end{col}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us whether you use a theorem-management package such as `amsthm` and `ntheorem` to define the theorem-like environments. (You appear to have set the tag `amsthm`, but it would be helpful if you confirmed that you indeed use `amsthm`.) Please also provide the code you use to set up these environments. And, please clarify what you mean by "take the number out of that isolated corollary". Are you maybe looking to create unnumbered corollaries?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem a few years ago, and it was solved on a French site, with a non-official package named `corollaries.sty`. If you're interested, is there a link where I might post it?

Comment: @Mico: As I understand it, the corollaries to a theorem (or a proposition or whatever) have to be numbered only if they are more than one.

Comment: Package `xcntperchap` could help, but not easy out of the box here, and without seeing a compilable document, it's guessing only

Comment: Is there a starred version to use?

Comment: @Mico, my question is generic (for ``amsthm`` as well as ``ntheorem``), and as such should not require any code, but since you insist, here it is, a bunch of begin and end for the same environments.

Comment: @PauloNey: It's not generic because each `theorem` package has a different setup of code in order to generate the output

Comment: @Bernard. Could you post the non-official package?

Comment: @PauloNey: I don't think I can post this kind of things on the site (or I don't know how to). The zipped archive is 175 kb (.sty+doc (in French)+examples).

Comment: @Bernard, you can place it in your Dropbox and post a link here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a Dropbox, but I'll try to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution with `xcntperchap`, tracking the number of corollaries per theorem and checking whether there is only one of them for a specific theorem, however, this is nothing that works out of the box -- some tweaking has to be done.

If this is the case, `\thecol` is let to `\relax` and the `.` is removed from the corollary header by a patch, but only locally.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\theteo}{\arabic{teo}}

\newtheorem{col}{Corolário}
\renewcommand{\thecol}{\arabic{col}}


\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}

\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithin*{col}{teo}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xcntperchap}

\RegisterTrackCounter{teo}{col}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{col}{%
  % Check whether there is more than corollary for the current (!) teo environment. If there's only one, \let\thecol\relax and kick the `\the\thm@headpunct` out of `\@begintheorem
  \edef\corollary@num{\ObtainTrackedValueExp{teo}{col}}%
  \ifx\corollary@num\empty
  % Do nothing if the result of \ObtainTrackedValueExp is \empty
  \else
  % check if the number is 1
  \ifnum1=\corollary@num%
  \let\thecol\relax% silence \thecol
  % Kick the . in the theorem header
  \xpatchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\the\thm@headpunct}{}{}{}
  \addtocounter{col}{-1}%
  \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{teo}
The first theorem
\end{teo}

   \begin{col}
     The first corollary
   \end{col}
   \begin{col}
     The second corollary
   \end{col}

\begin{teo}
The second theorem
\end{teo}

   \begin{col}
     Unique corollary to the theorem -- should have no number.
   \end{col}

\begin{teo}
The third theorem
\end{teo}

   \begin{col}
     The first corollary
   \end{col}
   \begin{col}
     The second corollary
   \end{col}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Updating with resetting of corollaries**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\theteo}{\arabic{teo}}

\newtheorem{col}{Corolário}
\renewcommand{\thecol}{\arabic{col}}


\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}

\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithin*{col}{teo}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xcntperchap}

\RegisterTrackCounter{teo}{col}


\makeatletter

\newif\if@resetcorollary
\AtBeginEnvironment{col}{%
  % Check whether there is more than corollary for the current (!) teo environment. If there's only one, \let\thecol\relax and kick the `\the\thm@headpunct` out of `\@begintheorem
  \edef\corollary@num{\ObtainTrackedValueExp{teo}{col}}%
  \ifx\corollary@num\empty
  \else
  \ifnum1=\corollary@num%
  \let\thecol\relax%
  \xpatchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\the\thm@headpunct}{}{}{}
  \addtocounter{col}{-1}%
  \fi
  \fi
}


\AtEndEnvironment{col}{%
  \if@resetcorollary
  \edef\corollary@num{\ObtainTrackedValueExp{teo}{col}}%
  \ifx\corollary@num\empty
  \else
  \ifnum1=\corollary@num%
  \setcounter{col}{0}%
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
}

\@resetcorollarytrue

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{teo}
The first theorem
\end{teo}

   \begin{col}
     The first corollary
   \end{col}
   \begin{col}
     The second corollary
   \end{col}

\begin{teo}
The second theorem
\end{teo}

   \begin{col}
     Unique corollary to the theorem -- should have no number.
   \end{col}

\begin{teo}
The third theorem
\end{teo}

   \begin{col}
     The first corollary
   \end{col}
   \begin{col}
     The second corollary
   \end{col}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Do you have to run latex twice? One thing I am curious is why the counter is not going back to zero after Theorem 3?

Comment: @PauloNey: You have to run twice at least in order to get the information correctly (which is basically always the case for LaTeX) And it does not reset because your initial version didn't have the resetting as well.

Comment: @PauloNey: I've added a version with resetting by using the `\@resetcorollarytrue` or `\@resetcorollaryfalse` macros

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks for the nice and round solution. This is a great improvement to LaTeX. You should make this a standard option of your package and add example of it to the documentation. It would help people write better books.

Comment: @PauloNey: I can add the example of course, but 'standard option' is confusing. The given answer  is a special solution for a special use - case. Other authors/users want to have a totally different behaviour and request another 'standard option' then.

Comment: I tried to work out the case where you could have Corollaries to Theorems and to Propositions at the same time and I am not getting it. From my reading of the code I just needed another block for the Propositions - but I am missing something ... what I mean is a set up where you could have unique Corollaries to Theorems and unique Corollaries to Propositions.

Comment: @PauloNey: Another question, of course. You asked for corollaries and theorems, changing the question is not kosher

Comment: Cool! Let's do another question ...