# Dynamic counter for corollaries of Theorems and Propositions at the same time

Tags: amsthm, chngcntr

In the question [Dynamic counters for corollaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393980/dynamic-counter-for-corollaries) Christian Hupfer has give a beautiful answer using his package `xcntperchap` in which corollaries of a Theorem receive numbers 1, 2, 3,... for each Theorem and receive NO NUMBERING if it is only one per Theorem.

In a general mathematical setting, you can Corollaries to BOTH Theorems and Propositions at the same time.

How can we expand his solution to have NO numbers in unique corollaries of a Theorem and of a Proposition?

A structure like

```
Theorem 1
  Corollary 1
  Corollary 2
Theorem 2
  Corollary 
Proposition 3
  Corollary 1
  Corollary 2
Proposition 4
  Corollary
```

Comment: Tracking counters that have multiple masters (i.e. resetting counters) is a pain in the neck...

Comment: In my opinion this gives readers a hard time when looking for statements from cross references. How can one know whether proposition 3 comes before or after theorem 2? You will have to always add the page reference. Using a unique numbering sequence for *all* statements is the easiest way to cope with the problem.

Comment: @egreg This is the way classical books in math have been written. It is darn easy to refer to it as the "Corollary 5 of Theorem 3" or as the "Corollary of Theorem 4". If you want to check it out I can give you plenty of examples of classical books that have been written this way - the method of numbering went into disuse with LaTeX and a bit of laziness.

Comment: It is a bad method notwithstanding; I'm not talking about “corollary of”, but Lemma 3 that can appear before or after Proposition 32 and before or after Theorem 4. How is a reader supposed to know that? It wasn't LaTeX to push it into disuse, but practicality.

Comment: @egreg, Adding a page reference is the worst you can do among all possible solutions because ebooks have continuing scrolling and page numbers are completely irrelevant. I agree with you that continuous-together numbering is one of the best solutions for locating something -- but that should apply only to Lemmas, Propositions and Theorems -- not to Corollaries. Corollaries are tied to a specific Proposition/Theorem and the fact they are numbered 1, 2, ... show you the main result they follow from is nearby.

Comment: @PauloNey: egreg is right, it's not the best strategy. Therefore I will delete my solution

Comment: Gregorio is completely wrong on his assessment. Just to give an example in Algebra - the classical books of Herstein, van der Waerden, Birkhoff, Mac Lane and Jacobson have all been done in this fashion.

Comment: I'll post the solution so others can benefit from it.

Comment: @PauloNey -- some recent authors have taken to numbering *everything* -- theorems, corollaries, propositions, ..., and *equations* with a single counter.  it's not laziness -- it's an attempt to make it easier to find things.  and it makes a lot of sense when you consider that these days many readers will be looking for things by scrolling, not by page.  even with clickable hyperlinks, scrolling is still a common method of going back a "page" or several.

Comment: @PauloNey: I've made a ready to install `corollaries-tds.zip`; and I've put it in a shared DropBox directory, but as there's no more public links/directory, I need to give the list of authorized persons so I need an email address. In this case it might be as simple to send it directly, if you're always interested.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, Numbering of everything is good, it is the old German way that you find in many of the well typeset classics and it is extremely useful for finding things. And I agree completely that numbering Lemmas, Propositions and Theorems in this way is a good solution. Now "Corollaries" is another story because they are tied in with another main result, be it a Proposition or a Theorem. Most Lemmas.Propositions/Theorems stand by themselves -- Corollaries do not and they are tied in. This is the way most classicals have been written before LaTeX.

Comment: @Bernard. My e-mail is either "paulo@" that big university near San Francisco (not Stanford) or "pauloney@" at the big internet email provider that starts with the letter G.

Comment: I've posted with the pauloney@ address. Please let me know if there's any problem.

Comment: Oh my not this alternating counters again

Comment: I have no clue where the big deal here is. Why not an environment with a starred form which stays unnumbered? why complicate things to get it automatized? There is no problem with label/ref if for example you use a single counter for both kinds of corollaries allowing to create via refstepcounter suitable anchors (if hyperref); numbered corollaries need secondary counter which is reset by other structures.

Answer (score -1):

Christian Hupfer again had a nice solution -- then he decided to delete it after the comment from Enrico Gregório, who is probably the last person in the world I would expect such comment from -- he is well acquainted with the classics in Algebra and that is how all of them have been typeset before the onset of LaTeX.

The solution by Hupfer leaves only one thing to be desired -- he creates an additional "corollary of a proposition" environment to achieve his goal, and one should, in theory, be able to do it without.

In all, this solution as well as his previous [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393980/dynamic-counter-for-corollaries) are examples of his package `xcntperchap` which is extremely useful for other typeseting tasks.

What follow below is slightly altered and commented version of his code, mostly to make it easier to understand. First one start out the same way just setting out the preliminaries, as with the previous (one environment) solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\theteo}{\arabic{teo}}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\renewcommand{\theprop}{\arabic{prop}}
```

then define the standard corollary environment:

```
\newtheorem{col}{Corollary}[teo]
\renewcommand{\thecol}{\arabic{col}}
```

go on to define the new addition environment:

```
\newtheorem{propcol}{Corollary}[prop]
\renewcommand{\thepropcol}{\arabic{propcol}}
```

Go on to define the two scopes:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{col}{teo}
\counterwithin*{col}{prop}
```

and the tracking of the two counters:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xcntperchap}

\RegisterTrackCounter{teo}{col}
\RegisterTrackCounter{prop}{propcol}
```

and now the original code is repeated for `col` and `propcol`:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\if@resetcorollary

\AtBeginEnvironment{col}{%
  \edef\corollary@num{\ObtainTrackedValueExp{teo}{col}}%
  \ifx\corollary@num\empty
  \else
  \ifnum1=\corollary@num%
  \let\thecol\relax%
  \xpatchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\the\thm@headpunct}{}{}{}
  \addtocounter{col}{-1}%
  \fi
  \fi
}

\AtEndEnvironment{col}{%
  \if@resetcorollary
  \edef\corollary@num{\ObtainTrackedValueExp{teo}{col}}%
  \ifx\corollary@num\empty
  \else
  \ifnum1=\corollary@num%
  \setcounter{col}{0}%
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{propcol}{%
  \edef\corollary@num{\ObtainTrackedValueExp{prop}{propcol}}%
  \ifx\corollary@num\empty
  \else
  \ifnum1=\corollary@num%
  \let\thepropcol\relax%
  \xpatchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\the\thm@headpunct}{}{}{}
  \addtocounter{propcol}{-1}%
  \fi
  \fi
}

\AtEndEnvironment{propcol}{%
  \if@resetcorollary
  \edef\corollary@num{\ObtainTrackedValueExp{prop}{propcol}}%
  \ifx\corollary@num\empty
  \else
  \ifnum1=\corollary@num%
  \setcounter{propcol}{0}%
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
}
\@resetcorollarytrue
\makeatother
```

and then now you can use it as:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{teo}
  The first theorem
\end{teo}

\begin{col}
  The first corollary
\end{col}
\begin{col}
  The second corollary
\end{col}

\begin{teo}
  The second theorem
\end{teo}

\begin{col}
  Unique corollary to the theorem -- should have no number.
\end{col}

\begin{prop}
  A proposition
\end{prop}

\begin{propcol}
  The unique proposition corollary -- no number
\end{propcol}

\begin{teo}
The third theorem
\end{teo}

\begin{col}
  The first corollary
\end{col}
\begin{col}
  The second corollary
\end{col}

\end{document}
```

It is not exactly what I was looking for, because of the use of a different environment, but nonetheless a great solution for a problem that was created in the world of math by LaTeX.

Comment: Please, remove the personal comments

Comment: The downvote isn't by me, but it's understandable, by posting ('stealing') code that I 'developed' and deleted soon afterwards because I didn't think about the references to such 'double' - master corollaries -- it's a weird approach, even if this has been done in the past in 'famous' textbooks

Comment: Why is it a weird approach? Do you mean weird approach from the point of view of typesetting or from the point of view of LaTeX?  It is not only used by the masters, it is used on the majority of good books before the advent of LaTeX, when they all either became labelled "Corollary 1" or someone has to use a separate command to un-number it. I am still trying to make it work with one environment only - but it is very painful.

Comment: Masters of math not publishing. Alternate numbering is just bad and inconsiderate design. Majority of good books use proper numbering.

Comment: @percursse, this has absolutely nothing to do with alternating numbering. You can use unumbered unique corollaries with any numbering schema you prefer.